# Get scroll position of an element to synchronize with another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a div that is scrollable (both x and y), and in order to synchronize the scroll position with another div I need its scroll position. Unfortunately `.position()` and `.offset()` don't help me. Is there another JS/JQuery approach I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
$('#source').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#target').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    $('#target').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```